# How to compiling InfluxDB from source code

Tags: go, influxdb, flux

When i compile the influxDB, I meet a problem. I can't find the `flux.pc` file.

The error info is :

```
skyfire@skyfire:~/goproject/src/github.com/influxdata/influxdb$ go install ./...
# /bin/pkg-config --cflags  -- flux
Package flux was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `flux.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'flux' found
/bin/pkg-config: exit status 1
skyfire@skyfire:~/goproject/src/github.com/influxdata/influxdb$
```

This is my compile commands:

```
cd $GOPATH
mkdir -p src/github.com/influxdata
git clone https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb.git
cd influxdb
go install ./...
```

My go version is `go version go1.13.8 linux/amd64`

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: Did you find an answer? I am trying to compile flux repl and have the same problem...
The standard procedure doesn't work either and I don't understand why...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the readme, compiling influxdb works like this:
https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb/blob/master/README.md