# how to build influxdb rust source?

Tags: rust, influxdb

I am a bit surprised that InfluxDB official document does not give an step by step guide to build its rust code base. I have found [How to compiling InfluxDB from source code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64634734/how-to-compiling-influxdb-from-source-code). However it's talking about the go code base. As far as I know the latest InfluxDB has switched to rust already.

I did git clone from [InfluxDB at github](https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb.git). I asked an online AI chatbot about it. It suggests the following steps after cloning:

```bash
cd influxdb_iox
cargo build
```

I am working on a Debian 9 box. It's my first time to deal with rust. I did following to have it installed.

```bash
sudo apt install rustc
rustc --version

> rustc 1.34.2

cargo --version

> cargo 1.34.0

cd influxdb_iox
cargo build

> error: failed to parse manifest at `/home/username/work/influxdb/influxdb_iox/Cargo.toml`

> Caused by:
>  invalid type: map, expected a sequence for key `package.authors`
```

My code tip is:

```bash
git log

> commit bb6a5c0bf6968117251617cda99cb39a5274b6dd
> Author: Jamie Strandboge <jamie@influxdata.com>
> Date:   Thu Nov 2 12:16:13 2023 +0000
>
>    chore: ignore Go in .github/dependabot.yml, take 3 (#24439)
>
>    Update to use the documented dependency-name: "*" methodology rather
>    than an undocumented example.
>
>    References:
>    - https://docs.github.com/en/code-security/dependabot/dependabot-version-updates/configuration-options-for-the-dependabot.yml-file
```

Since I am fresh on rust, I am not sure whether it's a rustc/cargo version problem, since I am using a pretty old Debian?

I am appreciate anyone can share me their experience or point me to the right document. Also I wonder if there is a build method use traditional makefile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cargo 1.34.0` released in [2019](https://blog.rust-lang.org/2019/04/11/Rust-1.34.0.html).

The project you are trying to build uses specifies `edition = "2021"` in it's [`Cargo.toml`](https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb/blob/main/Cargo.toml).

I therefore suspect that your issue is that your rust toolchain is too old. Consider using `rustup` to get a newer rust toolchain,
or upgrade to a newer version of Debian.